# Figure window showing up matlab

Tags: image, matlab

I have written this code to help me compare different image histograms however when i run it i get a figure window popping up. I can't see anywhere in the code where i have written imshow and am really confused. Can anyone see why? thanks

```
%ensure we start with an empty workspace
clear

myPath= 'C:\coursework\'; %#'
number_of_desired_results = 5; %top n results to return

images_path = strcat(myPath, 'fruitnveg');
images_file_names = dir(fullfile(images_path, '*.png'));
images = cell(length(images_file_names), 3);
number_of_images = length(images);

%textures contruction
%loop through all textures and store them
disp('Starting construction of search domain...');
for i = 1:length(images)
    image = strcat(images_path, '\', images_file_names(i).name); %#'

    %store image object of image
    images{i, 1} = imread(image);
    %store histogram of image
    images{i, 2} = imhist(rgb2ind(images{i, 1}, colormap(colorcube(256))));
    %store name of image
    images{i, 3} = images_file_names(i).name;
    disp(strcat({'Loaded image '}, num2str(i)));
end
disp('Construction of search domain done');

%load the three example images

RGB1 = imread('C:\coursework\examples\salmon.jpg');
X1 = rgb2ind(RGB1,colormap(colorcube(256)));
example1 = imhist(X1);

RGB2 = imread('C:\coursework\examples\eggs.jpg');
X2 = rgb2ind(RGB2,colormap(colorcube(256)));
example2 = imhist(X2);

RGB3 = imread('C:\coursework\examples\steak.jpg');
X3 = rgb2ind(RGB3,colormap(colorcube(256)));
example3 = imhist(X3);

disp('three examples loaded');

disp('compare examples to loaded fruit images');

results = cell(length(images), 2);

results2 = cell(length(images), 2);

results3 = cell(length(images), 2);

for i = 1:length(images)
    results{i,1} = images{i,3};
    results{i,2} = hi(example1,images{i, 2});
end

results = flipdim(sortrows(results,2),1);

for i = 1:length(images)
    results2{i,1} = images{i,3};
    results2{i,2} = hi(example2,images{i, 2});
end

results2 = flipdim(sortrows(results2,2),1);

for i = 1:length(images)
    results3{i,1} = images{i,3};
    results3{i,2} = hi(example3,images{i, 2});
end

results3 = flipdim(sortrows(results3,2),1);
```

Comment: Did you try putting some breakpoints and debugging your code?

Comment: It's coming from this bit of code, I really cant see why though!  images{i, 2} = imhist(rgb2ind(images{i, 1}, colormap(colorcube(256))));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `colormap` function sets the current figure's colormap, if there is no figure one is created.

The second parameter of `imhist` should be the number of bins used in the histogram, not the colormap.

Comment: is there a way to suppress the output?

Comment: If you take a look at : edit colormap, I dont think there is a way.

Comment: I put 'close all' at the end of the script and worked fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Run your code in the Matlab debugger, step through it line by line, and see when the figure window pops up. That'll tell you what's creating it.

Answer (score 1):

Etienne's answer is right for why you're getting a figure, but I'd just like to add that `colormap` is unnecessary in this code:

```
images{i, 2} = imhist(rgb2ind(images{i, 1}, colormap(colorcube(256))));
```

All you need is:

```
images{i, 2} = imhist(rgb2ind(images{i, 1}, colorcube(256)));
```

The second input of `rgb2ind` should be a colormap, yes. But the output of `colorcube` **is** a colormap already.  Unless you've got an existing figure and you either want to set the colormap of it or retrieve the colormap it is currently using, the actual function `colormap` is not necessary.

Other than opening an unnecessary figure, the output of your existing code won't be wrong, as I think in this situation `colormap` will just pass as an output argument the colormap it was given as an input argument.  For example, if you want to set the current figure colormap to one of the inbuilts **and** return the actual colormap:

```
cmap = colormap('bone');
```